# PHP put mysql connection in a separate function

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to put the code for connecting to mysql in a separate function in PHP and then use that function in other functions. Surprisingly, I haven't been able to find online resources on how to do that. I want to do something like this:

```
function connect_mysql() {

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "somepass", "testdb");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

return $con;
}

function some_function() {
connect_mysql(); 
// and use that connection here 
//so that I don't have to retype connection code again
}
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Danny, Tim answered below.

Comment: I still fail to see any problems with the code you posted.

Comment: Danny, I'm sorry it really was kind of vague. It's a bit complicated and long to explain everything here, but to be short about it, I misused including connect_mysql() function in another function body. Sorry to confuse you and thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in the following manner, using a [static variable](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) inside of `connect_mysql` so only one MySQL connection is ever created:

```
function connect_mysql() {
    static $con = null;
    if ($con == null) {
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "somepass", "testdb");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            return null;
        }
    }
    return $con;
}

function some_function() {
    $con = connect_mysql();
    $con->prepare(...);
}
```

This is an example of the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: I marked it and it said, I'd get an answer in a few minutes. Although, I don't know what that means.

Comment: @Davit You just need to wait a little longer `;)`

Answer (score 0):

Two thinks to consider:

(1) If you want to continue the object in your function `some_function()`, then use a variable for it:

Example:

```
function some_function() {
    $my = connect_mysql();
    $my->query('some great sql query...');
}
```

(2) To improve your connection function `connect_mysql()` you should exit it with a defined state whenever it fails to connect, maybe like this:

```
function connect_mysql() {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "somepass", "testdb");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        return false;   // <- exit here....
    }

    return $con;
}
```

Thats not necessarily required, but it helps you detect problems outside of your function and maintain the code when it gets bigger.

Comment: That's a useful information Bjoern. Thanks!